# Pandas Series to_numpy() preserve names of indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas series that I want to convert to a numpy array. The product names are displayed but I cannot access them. The real question is finding the names and essentially storing them in key-value pairs but in an array as opposed to a dict (format needed for pie chart)

```
data = pd.read_csv('./data/clean_data/cleaned_data.csv')
ser = data.groupby(['Product']).sum()['QuantityOrdered']
```

Output

```
Product
batteries                7661
charging cable          15187
...                       ...
eraser                   7538
```

```
vals = ser.to_numpy()
```

What it looks like now

```
[7661, 15187, ..., 7538]
```

What I want it to look like:

```
[[batteries, 7661],[charging cable, 15187, ...]
```

Comment: What array shape and dtype do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`ser.iteritems()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iteritems.html) (or `list(ser.iteritems())` if you directly need the results as a list), not `ser.to_numpy()`.